# java - how to convert from java.net.URI to org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

I need a utility method / class to convert from / to java.net.URI to org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI.

I could not find any existing convenient utility class.

Could anyone advice me?

Thanx

Comment: Other than converting it to string and then converting back?

Comment: Actually I need a method sth like public java.net.URI parseURI(org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI input)                                                     It seems that the constructor URI(String original) is deprecated for org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI... And this makes me think that I should not rely string forms of these classes during conversion??

Comment: It's deprecated in favor of another constructor that also takes a boolean that says whether the string is URI-encoded or not. It's not deprecated because strings are no good. The whole point of a URI that it is a uniform way to represent a resource with a string.